# How to use Matlab's linprog or intlinprog to yield a MAXIMUM solution to optimization?

Tags: matlab, optimization

So I need to use MatLab to solve an optimization problem but this question doesn't have to be for a specific problem, this question is for optimization in general.

How do you get `linprog()` or `intlinprog()` to get the maximum solution? As far as I know, these functions only find the minimum solution to optimization problems but I need the maximum solutions.

How do I get the linear programming functions on matlab to return the maximum solution of an optimization problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take the -ve of the function and find the minima

Answer (score 2):

From documentation entries for the function `linprog` the function is called like that

```
x = linprog(f, A, b)
```

in order to find **min f'x**.

If you instead call

```
x = linprog(-f, A, b)
```

you will find **max f'x**

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the sign of the objective function f (vector of multipliers) with a negative sign. Maximizing a function is the same as minimizing the negative of the same function.